# How to change highlight color on QTreewidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have wrote an app using QTreeWidget. Currently when selecting an item using the mouse, this item is highlighted in blue as probably default palette.

How can I change the property to modify the highlight color when a QTreeWidgetItem is selected using the mouse. For example, the color is no more blue but the one I want.

My TreeWidget is defined as below:

```
setSortingEnabled(true);
setColumnWidth(0, 400);
setExpandsOnDoubleClick(true);

setAlternatingRowColors(true);

QPalette p = palette();
p.setColor( QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(0xef, 0xef, 0xef) );
setPalette(p);

setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

I have also subclass the QTreeWidgetItem but it's mostly to add parameter and change the font by default

```
MyTreeWidgetItem::MyTreeWidgetItem()
{
    isFolder = false;
    filename = NULL;

    QFont ItemFont = QFont(FONT_TYPE);
    ItemFont.setPointSize(FONT_SIZE_MEDIUM);
    setFont(0,ItemFont);
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you try a stylesheet? `QTreeWidget::item:pressed,QTreeWidget::item:selected{background-color:#FFCC00;}` will change the tree highlight color.

Comment: I use delegates for this.